# how to assign value from JavaScript function to global variable in same script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I write code for getting a date, but that date(variable) is only defined in the same function but i need makes that as a global variable. what i needs to do that? there is part of the code,

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >

var year = "";
var month = "";
var day = ""
var hour = "";
var minut = "";
var time = "";


function myFunction() {
    year = document.getElementById("id1").value;
    month = document.getElementById("id2").value;
    day = document.getElementById("id3").value;
    hour = document.getElementById("id4").value;
    minut = document.getElementById("id5").value;
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(hour);
    d.setMinutes(minut);
    d.setDate(day);
    d.setMonth(month - 1);
    d.setFullYear(year);
    var now = new Date();
    today = now.toISOString();
    var time = d.toISOString();
}

var resource = {
    "summary": "Sample Event testing " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1),
    "start": {
        "dateTime": //set date for this place
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": twoHoursLater
    }
}; 

</script>
```

this is part of the code.
I need set time for ""dateTime"://set date for this place" this place.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Make MyFunction to return the date value which you have computed. call MyFunction method from your object

```
    function GetDateTime(){
    // get the date time based on your requirement
    year =document.getElementById("id1").value;
    month =document.getElementById("id2").value;
    day =document.getElementById("id3").value;
    hour =document.getElementById("id4").value;
    minut =document.getElementById("id5").value;
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(hour);
    d.setMinutes(minut);
    d.setDate(day);
    d.setMonth(month-1);
    d.setFullYear(year);                    
    var now = new Date();
    today = now.toISOString();
    var time= d.toISOString();
    return "DateValue"
}
```

from your global variable do this

```
var obj = {
 summary : "Summary",
 Start: { dateTime: GetDateTime()},
 End:{dateTime: {GetDateTime()}
}
```